# T-SQL grouping with dynamic column number

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, dynamic, relational-database

Let's say I have a 1D-like table like this:

```
TBL_1
[ Task  ][ Entity ][ Timespan ]
[ TASK1 ][  ID1   ][    3     ]
[ TASK2 ][  ID2   ][    4     ]
[ TASK2 ][  ID1   ][    5     ]
[ TASK1 ][  ID2   ][    6     ]
```

How would I turn it into a 2D-like view like this:

```
[ Entity ][ TASK1 ][ TASK2 ]
[  ID1   ][   3   ][   5   ]
[  ID2   ][   6   ][   4   ]
```

Given that the number of tasks should be dynamic?

My current solution looks like that:

```
SELECT A.Entity, B.Task TASK1, C.Task TASK2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ENTITY FROM TBL_1) A
LEFT JOIN TBL_1 B
ON A.Entity = B.Entity AND B.Task = 'TASK1'
LEFT JOIN TBL_1 C
ON A.Entity = C.Entity AND C.Task = 'TASK2'
```

But this requires me to "Hardcode" the tasks. How can-I make this dynamic?

Thank you very much!

Comment: look up pivot for which ever version of sql server you are using.

Comment: Reference this thread on PIVOT tables:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: @BoeroBoy those links are for MySQL and the question is referencing sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You can use a Dynamic SQL Pivot for this. This tactic will get the column names to transform on execution of the query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(task) 
                    from t1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT entity, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select entity, task, timespan
                from t1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(timespan)
                for task in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89495/4)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for! I'll have to learn how this whole STUFF/XML/PATH/PIVOT thing works, though :-)

Comment: Is there any way I could do a SELECT ... FROM [THIS_SOLUTION_ENCAPSULATED] with this? VIEWS & FUNCTIONS don't seem to allow Dynamic SQL, we can't SELECT from a Stored Procedure

Comment: how are you planning on using this?  You can place this code in a stored proc and get the data from that.

Comment: Well, let's say the resulting (pivoted) dataset is named TBL_2, I would like to be able to do something like `SELECT * FROM TBL_2 WHERE Entity LIKE 'ID%'`, or `Task1>20`, or whatever... For now I made a Stored Proc, but I can't WHERE on it, or JOIN, or everything we use to do on tables... For now it is no problem, but it would be more... elegant.

Comment: @m6a-uds you will want to look at inserting the values from the stored procedure into a temp table.  Look at using `OPENROWSET`, there are answer on SO about doing it

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in the spirit of what you were trying.  However, using a group by is much simpler than what you were attempting:

```
SELECT ENTITY,
       max(case when t.task = 'Task1' then timespan end) as task1,
       max(case when t.task = 'Task2' then timespan end) as task2,
       . . .
FROM TBL_1 t
group by entity
```

To dynamically generate the column, you would need to use dynamic SQL.  Is this what you really want?

Comment: True. I think that the OP is looking for a way to dynamically generate the column aliases as the filter